# Android Recycler View (Grid layoud manager)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Is there any way we can make recycler view with GridLayoutManager and orientation Horizontal to show items in a sequence horizontal wise

Currently how items are drawn(image provided)

[Items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afkpk.png)

0 2 4 6 8

1 3 5 7 9

but, I want to display like

0 1 2 3 4

5 6 7 8 9

No more than two rows

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to make it horizontal

```
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(),4);
    gridLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL); // set Horizontal Orientation
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
```

[Refer Here For Additional Information](https://abhiandroid.com/materialdesign/recyclerview-gridview.html)